# Problems with mailR in shiny apps

Tags: r, sendmailr

When I upload my application in shiny apps and press the button to send mail, it does not work and the application is dropped could help me[`the application doesn´t work`

```html
 observeEvent(input$sends,{
      send.mail(from = isolate("ejemplo_correos365@mail.com"),
                to = c("user@mail.com"),
                subject=isolate("Actividades"),
                html = T,
                smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.office365.com", port = 587,
                            user.name = "ejemplo_correos365@mail.com", passwd = "*************", tls = T),
                authenticate =T,
                send = T)
      
    })
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Isxnu.png)

Comment: What does your shinyapps (do you mean shinyapps.io?) log file tell you?

Comment: It could be important if you have a free or paid account?

Comment: it is paid account, now i solve this with a institutional e-mail